# Finding the mass of an egg from impulse necessary to break it (from dropping it)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

I came across [this](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/Physics-Interactives/Momentum-and-Collisions/Egg-Drop/Egg-Drop-Interactive) simulation from https://www.physicsclassroom.com.

It didn't say how much force was necessary to break the average egg, so I looked it up ([link](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk00JDL6iryq4drIfW3rjsOLTjE3Z2w%3A1584914332561&ei=nN93XozoIeqJjLsP84ax6AM&q=how%20much%20force%20does%20it%20take%20to%20break%20a%20egg%20in%20newtons&oq=how%20much%20force%20does%20it%20take%20to%20break%20a%20egg%20in%20n&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.35i39j0i13.6240.6985..7782...0.2..0.109.468.4j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i22i30j0i8i13i30.7TPhUrVNcnY)):

> It takes 25 Newtons to break an egg. If you drop an egg from 25 ft,
>   the egg will be travelling at ~40 ft/sec (12.2 m/sec) or roughly 27
>   mph when it hits the ground.

I wanted to find out what value they used for the mass so I plugged in the numbers:

$$25N*t = m_e*12.2m/s \\
9.8m/s^2 = \frac{12.2m/s}{t}$$

and solved it:

$$25N*1.2s = m_e*12.2m/s \Leftrightarrow m_e = 2.4kg \\
9.8m/s = \frac{12.2m/s}{t} \Leftrightarrow t = 1.2s$$

An egg obviously doesn't have that much mass so what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first equation is fine, you are equating the impulse exerted on the egg to its change in momentum by calculating the impluse. The impulse is defined as $J = \int_0^\tau F(t) dt$, where $\tau$ is the time over which the collision occurs. In your equation you use a simplified form $J = F_\mathrm{ave} \tau$, so the force you are calculating is the *average* force experienced by the egg.

But it is important to note that $\tau$ is not the descent time of the egg, which is what you appear to be calculating in your second equation. It is the time over which the collison occurs: if the egg lands on a soft surface, this time will be long, and so the average force will be lower. Conversely, if the surface is hard, the average force will be higher (but will have a shorter duration). Unless you have an estimate for this time, by modelling the details of the form of the collision, you cannot calculate the weight of the egg in this way.

Comment: Is there a way of calculating it?

Comment: You need to have an estimate for the collision time, which will depend on the type of floor (e.g. is it wood, concrete, etc). It's probably between 10 - 100 ms. Once you know that, then you can find the mass of the egg.

Comment: I have down voted because we shouldn't be answering off-topic questions